# update one dictionary with another by adding values rather then replacing it

Tags: python, dictionary

I have many dictionaries like this:

```
dict1 = {1:[1,2,3],2:[2,3,4]}
dict2 = {2:[3,4,5],3:[4,5,6]}
```

I need to get

```
dict = {1:[1,2,3],2:[2,3,4,3,4,5],3:[4,5,6]}
#                       ^
#                       | order is unimportant
```

What is the best way of doing it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple iteration an extending list...

```
for key, value in dict2.iteritems():
    dict1.setdefault(key, []).extend(value)
```

Comment: Fine. It can be written in one line ``[ dict1.setdefault(k, []).extend(v) for k,v in dict2.iteritems()]``

Comment: Using a list comprehension purely for side effects is ugly.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through the keys of dict2; if the same key exists in dict1, concatenate the lists and set in dict1; otherwise just set in dict1

Answer (score 1):

```
dict1 = {1:[1,2,3],2:[2,3,4]}
dict2 = {2:[3,4,5],3:[4,5,6]}

dicts = [dict1, dict2]
new_dict = {}

for d in dicts:
  for k, v in d.iteritems():
    if new_dict.has_key(k):
      new_dict[k] = new_dict[k] + v
    else:
      new_dict[k] = v
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = {'a' : [1,2], 'b' : [3,4]}
b = {'a' : [3,4], 'b' : [1,2]}

for key in a.keys():
    for elem in a[key]:
        b[key].append(elem)
```

Comment: KeyError on the asker's example, since their "b" list does not contain a 1 key.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, maybe there's some clever way to do it with reduce, but why not just write code like a normal person.

```
dict = {}
for each_dict in (dict1, dict2, ...): # ... is not real code
    for key, value in each_dict:
        if not dict.has_key(key):
            dict[key] = []
        dict[key] += value # list append operator
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have many dictionaries like this:

This way lets you "glue together" multiple dictionaries at a time:

```
dict(
  (k, sum((d.get(k, []) for d in dicts), []))
  for k in set(sum((d.keys() for d in dicts), []))
)
```