# Iterating over dictionary yields string values to be split into characters

Tags: python, dictionary, split, character

**Set-Up**

I create dictionaries in a loop, all containing the same keys but different values.

A part of one of the dictionaries as example,

```
data = {
        'type': 'An apartment',
        'sublet': 'Indifferent',
       }
```

At the end of the loop, I append the values of each dictionary `data` to a 'large' dictionary `all_data`.

I create `all_data = {}` before commencement of the loop.

---

**Problem**

When I append the values of `data` to `all_data`, Python splits the string values of `data` into characters. E.g.

```
all_data {
         'type': ['A', 'n', ' ', 'a', 'p', 'a', 'r', 't', 'm', 'e', 'n', 't'],
         'sublet': ['I', 'n', 'd', 'i', 'f', 'f', 'e', 'r', 'e', 'n', 't'],
         }
```

I append the values via the following code (which I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7206686/7326714)),

```
for key, value in data.items():
     all_data.setdefault(key,[]).extend(value)
```

How do I obtain,

```
all_data {
         'type': 'An apartment',
         'sublet': 'Indifferent',
         }
```

Such that after the loop is finished, I obtain,

```
all_data {
         'type': 'An apartment', 'A room', 'An apartment',
         'sublet': 'Indifferent', 'Yes', 'Yes'
         }
```

where order matters.

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26910708/merging-dictionary-value-lists-in-python) is a nice one-liner!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `.append()` not `.extend()`.

```
for key, value in data.items():
    all_data.setdefault(key,[]).append(value)
```

`.extend()` extends the list with the given iterable. A string is an iterable of characters, therefore the target list will receive a single character as each item.

Comment: I'll be damned. Thanks!

Comment: @LucSpan If this answer solved your question, click on the check-mark. It will mark the question as solved and give reputation to you and the answerer. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: I know, just had to wait.